# TeamCity Build Triggers to exclude some directories

Tags: teamcity, teamcity-8.0, teamcity-9.0

I have a rule in Build Triggers to not trigger a build if a commit happens on a directory:

Here is the directory structure of our code

```
web      => Web Application code. Should trigger Build1
api      => Backend Code. Should trigger Build2
```

When a git commit happens on web files, I just want to trigger Build1 and not Build2. So, I have the trigger rules setup this way:

```
+:.
-:api/**
```

This worked for couple hours, but I started seeing both builds getting triggered when api files are checked in and vice versa.

I have also tried the following configurations and nothing seem to work.

Config2:

```
-:api/**
```

Config3:

```
+:web/**
```

Config4:

```
-:**
+:web/**
```

Config5:

```
-:.
+:web/**
```

Whats the right build trigger config for my usecase?

This happens both on Teamcity 8 and 9

Comment: Are you using checkout on an agent?  Apparently there are limitations around checkout rules with Git and you can only map the entire repository to a directory (https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TCD9/Git#Git-Limitations).

Comment: I do checkout on agent, but I don't have any checkout rules

Answer (score 2):

You don't need the wildcards, and if you use a `+` rule you don't need the `-:.` rule.  This should work for Build 1:

```
+:web/**
```

This should work for build 2:

```
+:api/**
```

Comment: Tried it, still 2 builds getting triggered

Answer (score -1):

I assume you are aware of this site: https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TCD9/Configuring+VCS+Triggers#ConfiguringVCSTriggers-VCSTriggerRules

You can start playing with single file, trying to figure it out if it is still triggering both builds.